# Objects not same in bi-directional mapping between entities

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities - LoginUser and LoginUserToken. I have created a bi-directional mapping between the two by using @OneToMany on the list of tokens in the User entity and @ManyToOne on the User associated with the Token.

LoginUser.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<LoginUserToken> tokens;
```

LoginUserToken.java

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_ID, referencedColumnName = LoginUser.COLUMN_ID, nullable = false)
@JsonBackReference
private LoginUser user;
```

When I query a User and a Token associated with this user, the User object is different from the object of the user retrieved from the Token object. 
Is there any way I can avoid that? Make sure I get same objects so that can do an object level comparison.

Comment: The code matters. Post the code.

Comment: @JBNizet done. pls check

Comment: Post the test case reproducing the problem you're facing.